# Showing Description in a TextBox when selecting the correspodent ID on ComboBox

Tags: telerik

I'm trying to either have a text box, that shows description when user picks the corresponding id on a ComboBox. Or alternately to show ID - Description in the same ComboBox.

Any idea how achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Find below with Telerik controls

> C# Razor

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        @(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
                         .Name("color")
                         .DataTextField("Text")
                         .DataValueField("Value")
                         .Events(e => e.Change("change"))
                         .BindTo(new List<SelectListItem>() {
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Black",
              Value = "1"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Orange",
              Value = "2"
          },
          new SelectListItem() {
              Text = "Grey",
              Value = "3"
          }
                         })
                         .Value("1")
                         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width: 100%" })
        )
    </div>

<div class="col-md-4">
        @Html.Kendo().TextBox().Name("txtColor")
    </div>
</div>
```

> Script

```
<script>
    function change() {
        $("#txtColor").val($("#color").val());
    }
</script>
```